# Error in cache list when pulling from World Bank for R

Tags: r

Tried to pull the following data via WorldBank and narrowing it down to the following year but faced this error. Tried using cache=new_cache and everything else but can't seem to clear this error. Data is still showing 1960 onwards.

```r
data1 <-WDI(indicator= c("IT.NET.USER.ZS", "SP.POP.TOTL", "SP.URB.TOTL.IN.ZS", "IT.NET.SECR.P6", start = 2009, end = 2019), extra = TRUE)
```

Error - These indicators could not be downloaded, and they do not appear in the cached list of available World Bank data series: 2009, 2019

Comment: Your start and end arguments are the last 2 items within the vector of indicators. Move that closing paren back.

Comment: I tried and still faced the same error. -These indicators could not be downloaded, and they do not appear in the cached list of available World Bank data series: 2009, 2019, FALSE
```data3 <-WDI(indicator= c("IT.NET.USER.ZS", "SP.POP.TOTL", "SP.URB.TOTL.IN.ZS", "IT.NET.SECR.P6", start = 2009, end = 2019, extra = FALSE))
```

Comment: data3 <-WDI(indicator= c("IT.NET.USER.ZS", "SP.POP.TOTL", "SP.URB.TOTL.IN.ZS", "IT.NET.SECR.P6"), start = 2009, end = 2019, extra = FALSE)